# jQuery Cookie on slideToggle

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, jquery-cookie

I've a navigation bar, and a hidden sub navigation bar.
When I click on Page2 the hidden bar shows up (with slideToggle).
So far so good. Now the client wants, when the sub navigation
bar is shown, and he clicks on Page3 or Page1 again that
the sub navigation bar stays shown until he click on Page2 again.
I know that I need cookies for this. I've tried to make it by
myself but with no effort, because this is the first time
I work with JS cookies. I'm sure somebody knows how to do this
jQuery script

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Page1</a></li>
        <li id="item"><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">Page3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<br /><br />
<ul id="sub-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Subpage1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Subpage2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Subpage3</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    *{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    ul{list-style:none; font: 20px; float: left;}
    ul li{float: left; margin-right: 20px;}
    #sub-nav{font:14px; display: none;}
</style>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#item').click(function(){
            $('#sub-nav').slideToggle('fast');          
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sitepoint.com/eat-those-cookies-with-jquery/

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Setting a cookie with jQuery is as simple as this, where a cookie is created called "example" with a value of "foo" for the current path:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo");
```

removing this cookie

```
$.removeCookie("example");
```

read the cookie

```
$.cookie("example",  { path: '/' });//you might change the path here
```